# Using IF condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to query a remote machine and if the KB22334358 is found in the `systeminfo` output then exit, otherwise write hostname to `failed.txt`.

Why doesn't this work?

```
systeminfo /s "remotenamemachine" | find "KB22334358"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto nome else goto exit
:nome
systeminfo | find "Nome host" > C:\failed.txt
:exit
exit
```

Comment: Is the literal string `Nome host` supposed to appear in the output of `systeminfo`?

Comment: .. Note: A possible answer to my question is 'yes', *iff* the output of `system info` is translated for localized versions of Windows. Since my system is in English, I cannot easily check that.

Comment: Which host's name do you want to log? Is it the name of the remote machine or the name of the one where you are running the batch file?

Comment: The machine to wich i want to log the host name is the remote one.
The mean of this batch is to check if a machine got the KB22334358 fix installed. 
I want to execute this for 400+ remote machine.
In Windows english "nome host" is translated in "Host Name"

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you might need to use the `/s` switch as well when you connect the next time.  Also, you might want to make the `find` command not case sensitive by using `/i`.  You might also want to append to the failed.txt file, like so:

```
systeminfo /s "remotenamemachine" | find "KB22334358"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto nome else goto exit
:nome
systeminfo /s "remotenamemachine" | find /i "Nome host" >> C:\failed.txt
:exit
exit
```

Or you can use this triple `for /f` loop that gets it all in one shot:

**KB_Checker.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set comp_name=%*

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=" %%I in (`
    systeminfo /s "%comp_name%"
`) do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%k in (`
        echo %%I ^| findstr /v "^)" ^| findstr "KB22334358"
    `) do (
        for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%f in ('
            echo %%k ^| findstr /v "UTC"
        ') do (
            set temp_KB=%%f
        )
    )

    for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%h in (`
        echo %%I ^| findstr /i /C:"Nome host"
    `) do (
        for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%f in ('
            echo %%h ^| findstr /v "UTC"
        ') do (
            set hm=%%f
        )
    )
) 2> nul

set KB=!temp_KB!
if not defined KB echo !hm! >> C:\failed.txt
exit
```

***UPDATE***

I updated the script above to set the `comp_name` environment var.  You can pass the computer name into the script like so: `KB_Checker.bat computer_1` and it will process that

Comment: Do you know how to integrate to the last script with a list of machine name to query?

Comment: You can pass the computer name into the script/function or have a list of system names in a text file.

Comment: I shoukd be able to put an OU Active directory group aswell right?